# How to get height of the entire available space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the height of the entire available space in the web browser, so I can position a `div` halfway down the screen and stretching it all the way down.

I thought `document.body.clientHeight` would work, but that returned the amount of space that was being *taken up*, not total available space.

I also tried making a "wrapper" `div` around everything:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    //my other code
</div>
```

And getting the height of that, but that still returns taken up space.

How can I get the total available space in the web browser with Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

```
This method is also able to find the height of the window and document.

    $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
    $(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Comment: could try $('body').height(), however it will be less than the wondow height if the content of the page isn't higher than the viewport.

Comment: Never mind, `$(window).height()` works. Thanks! Will accept when SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

I you mean the space available in parent of the element, You can try this...

```
var entireHeight=$('#elementID').parent().height();

var siblingHeight=0;

var elementSiblings=$('#elementID').siblings();

$.each(elementSiblings, function() {
    siblingHeight= siblingHeight+$(this).height();
});
```

Subtracting the values i.e.

```
(entireHeight-siblingHeight)
```

should give you the available space.

Hope it helps.. :) Tell me If it aint working.

Answer (score 1):

***it is very simple***

var max_height=**screen.availHeight - (window.outerHight - window.innerHight)**

Answer (score 0):

A simple example with jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>
        A2CARE 2.0
    </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="jslib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getheight(){
            var d= document.documentElement;
            var b= document.body;
            var who= d.offsetHeight? d: b ;
            return who.clientHeight;

        }
        $(document).ready(function() {      
                var h = getheight();
                document.getElementById('tryme').style.height= h + 'px';
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="tryme" style="border: 2px solid red;">
        try me!
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use in javascript

```
screen.width
screen.height
```

u can assign like

```
document.getElementById("parentId").style.width = (screen.width - 100)+"px";
document.getElementById("parentId").style.height = (screen.height-300)+"px";
```